# Confirm form resubmission dialog in IE8 doesn't have focus

Tags: internet-explorer-8, focus

When the "Confirm form resubmission" dialog comes up (after pressing F5 refresh) in certain sites, I used to just press Enter or the space bar and it would hit enter.

In IE8, the dialog box doesn't have focus and I have to use my mouse to click Continue or Cancel.

I am not sure what to do to enable this feature or simply focus on the continue button.